# Function Value of an exponential function

Tags: calculus, functions

How to show that the following function is always positive for any $x > 0$

$$F(x) = e^{2x} - x^2 e^x - 2 e^x + 1$$

When I tried to use the first order Taylor approximation to $e^x = x +1$. I got $-x^3-x^2$ but when I draw the function for $x > 0$, it is positive expontential increasing function.

Comment: an idea : Try to divide by $2\exp(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(x) =(e^x -1)^2 - x^2 e^x $$
$$F' (x) = 2(e^x-1) e^x -(x^2 +2x) e^x =e^x (2 e^x -2 -x^2 -2x )> e^x \left(2\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2} \right) - 2-x^2 -2x \right)=0$$
for $x> 0$. So $F$ is monotone increasing for $x\geq 0$ hence $$F(x) >F(0) =0.$$